# last-child selecting all children in css?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to remove the last tab's border-right property... but both the nth-child property or the last-child property isn't working...
plus when i use nth-child(1) it selects all the children and doesn't work for other values

```
<!-- HTML Markup -->

<ul>
    <a href="#">
        <li>Solutions</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <li>Industries</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <li>Resources</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <li>Partners</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <li>About</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="button">
        <li>Enterprise</li>
    </a>
</ul>
```

```
/* CSS Code */


 ul:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

li {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 15px;
/*    border-right: 1px solid #a5a5a5;  */
    color: #1F222B;
}
li {
    border-right: 1px solid #ff0000;
}

li:nth-of-type(1) {
    border-right: 1px solid #00b2ff;
}


li:hover {
    border-right: 1px solid #F3EFF2;
    background: #1F222B;
    color: #F3EFF2;
}
```

Kindly help with the solution and the cause?
And is it possible to achieve the solution with 'li' tags inside the 'a' tag 
but with the floating 'li' tags?

Comment: you html is invalid, li should be child of ul

Comment: i've seen some youtube developers do this and it works fine...
it makes the whole area clickable.... without styling the a tag...

Comment: they are simply doing wrong ... use a validator and you will see: https://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add this CSS to remove the border from the last tab

```
a:last-child li {
border-right: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help mate... appreciate that.... but can you please tell why the
following code is not working even when this is the last li tag in my whole html doc
```
li:last-of-type{
    border-right:none;
}